# Issue in Extenction attribute ::setCode()

Tags: magento2, fatal-error

```
Fatal Error: 'Uncaught Error: Call to undefined method** SimplifiedMagento\\Database\\Api\\Data\\AffiliateMemberExtension::setCode() in \/var\/www\/html\/Magento2\/app\/code\/SimplifiedMagento\/Attribute\/Model\/Plugin\/CodeAttributeExtension.php:25
Stack trace:
#0 \/var\/www\/html\/Magento2\/vendor\/magento\/framework\/Interception\/Interceptor.php(135): SimplifiedMagento\\Attribute\\Model\\Plugin\\CodeAttributeExtension->aroundGetAffiliateMemberById(Object(SimplifiedMagento\\Database\\Model\\AffiliateMemberRepository\\Interceptor), Object(Closure), 1)
#1 \/var\/www\/html\/Magento2\/vendor\/magento\/framework\/Interception\/Interceptor.php(153): SimplifiedMagento\\Database\\Model\\AffiliateMemberRepository\\Interceptor->Magento\\Framework\\Interception\\{closure}(1)
#2 \/var\/www\/html\/Magento2\/generated\/code\/SimplifiedMagento\/Database\/Model\/AffiliateMemberRepository\/Interceptor.php(39): SimplifiedMagento\\Database\\Model\\AffiliateMemberRepository\\Interceptor->___callPlugins('getAffiliateMem...', Array, NULL)
#3 [internal function]: SimplifiedMagento\\Database\\Model\\AffiliateM' in '\/var\/www\/html\/Magento2\/app\/code\/SimplifiedMagento\/Attribute\/Model\/Plugin\/CodeAttributeExtension.php' 
on line 25
```

Comment: Please, add code of the `SimplifiedMagento\Database\Api\Data\AffiliateMemberExtension` class and of the `SimplifiedMagento/Attribute/Model/Plugin/CodeAttributeExtension.php` plugin. It is difficult to help you without that code.

Comment: this code is SimplifiedMagento\Database\Api\Data\AffiliateMemberExtension
already added. in my class

Comment: It's hard to say something without seeing a source code. You must add source code to you question if you want to get some help. Tipically your error means that method `setCode` does not exist in your class, but it's hard to understand why it is calling and where it should be defined.

Comment: You Have Defined the Method **setcode()** which doesn't exist. Please check whether it contains this method.